# jQuery UI Calendar Widget + Input Placeholders for IE8

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer-8

I am using jQuery UI's calendar widget for a form, and I just received word that the input placeholder is not showing up in IE8. IE8 doesn't support them, so I've been trying to implement a shim. One I found on here is the following:

https://github.com/parndt/jquery-html5-placeholder-shim

It is fairly simple, and straight forward, however it doesn't seem to work in IE8 still. What happens is that the input appears blank, then when clicked on, the placeholder appears, and it disappears once a date is selected.

I've tried re-initializing the plugin after the datepicker is drawn, but that doesn't seem to do anything for me.

Anyone have success combining jQuery UI Datepicker with an IE8 placeholder shim?